# Pivot Table in Pandas Count aggregate()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to take the count of 'STAGE' occurrence based on project, I used np.size as aggfunc but it return number of occurrence including the project, My count value become double if expected count is 3 means it return 6

[image]

I used the below code

```
df = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['Project'],columns=['Stage'], aggfunc=np.size, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need aggregate function `len`:

```
print (data_frame)
  Project Stage
0      an    ip
1     cfc    pe
2      an    ip
3      ap    pe
4     cfc    pe
5      an    ip
6     cfc    ip

df = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, 
                    index='Project',
                    columns='Stage', 
                    aggfunc=len, 
                    fill_value=0)
print (df)
Stage    ip  pe
Project        
an        3   0
ap        0   1
cfc       1   2
```

Another solution with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, 
                    index='Project',
                    columns='Stage', 
                    aggfunc='size', 
                    fill_value=0)
print (df)
Stage    ip  pe
Project        
an        3   0
ap        0   1
cfc       1   2
```

EDIT by comment:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#all code

df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Can we able to convert this pivot table into bar chart directly, Like project as in x - axis and stage as stacked bar